# Splits completely of a prime ideal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-factorization, ramification

Suppose that $K$ is a number field and $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal non-zero.

In general always exists a finite extension of $L$ of $K$ such that $\mathfrak p$ is ramified, for example $L=K(\sqrt f)$ with $f$ is a generator of maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_{K,\mathfrak p}$.

My question is about the existence of a finite extension $L$ of $K$ such that the factorization of $\mathfrak p$ is

$$\mathfrak p=\mathfrak P\mathfrak Q\prod J,$$
with $\mathfrak P$ and $\mathfrak Q$ are two distinct prime ideals and J is a ideal of $\mathcal O_L$ i.e. such that $\mathfrak p$ we have two distinct prime ideals above.

Or more generally if exist be a finite extension $L$ of $K$ such that
$$\mathfrak p=\mathfrak P_1\cdots\mathfrak P_r$$
with $r>1$ i.e. $\mathfrak p$ splits completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There always is a monic irreducible polynomial $f\in{\mathcal O}_K[t]$ that splits into distinct linear factors mod $\mathfrak p$. Then adjoining the root of such a polynomial gives an extension in which $\mathfrak p$ splits completely. To see that there is such a polynomial start with a (monic) not necessarily irreducible polynomial that splits completely into distinct linear factors mod $\mathfrak p$ and then, using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, add elements $\equiv0\mod\mathfrak p$ to the coefficients so that it becomes Eisenstein at some other prime so that it will be irreducible (maybe there is an easier way to do this?).

**Edit:** This only gives polynomials of degree $\leq N_{K/\Bbb Q}(\mathfrak p)$. You can get polynomials of arbitrary degree with the desired property by modifying this idea slightly. Take any monic polynomial $f\in{\mathcal O}_K[t]$ that splits completely into distinct linear factors over ${\mathcal O}_K$. Then modify its coefficients so that the resulting polynomial is still $\mathfrak p$-adically close to $f$ and will therefore still split into distinct linear factors over $K_{\mathfrak p}$, but is Eisenstein at some other prime and therefore irreducible. Then adjoining a root of that polynomial gives an extension in which $\mathfrak p$ splits completely.

Comment: The degree of $f$ is arbitrary for each $n\in\mathbb N$. And  why the roots the $f$ they correspond with factor of $\mathfrak p$? thanks

Comment: I have included an edit that allows the degree to be arbitrary, previously it was bounded by $N({\mathfrak p})=|{\mathcal O}_K/\mathfrak p|$. The factors of $\mathfrak p$ in the extension correspond to the irreducible factors of the polynomial defining the extension over the completion $K_{\mathfrak p}$.

Comment: sorry for tha late. This is possible  to demand that $L/K$ is Galois extension with the same requirements ? your extension is Galois?

Comment: Yes, take the Galois closure of the current extension. Note that a prime splits completely in an extension iff it splits completely in the Galois closure.